# using hundreds of child processes in Windows?

Tags: windows, process

I have a Windows application which uses many third-party modules of questionable reliability.  My app has to create many objects from those modules, and one bad object may cause a lot of problems.

I was thinking of a multi-process scheme where the objects are created in a separate process (the interfaces are basically all the same, so creating the cross-process communication shouldn't be so difficult).  At the most extreme, I'm considering one object per process so I might end up with anywhere between 20 processes and a few hundred processes launch from my main app.

Would that cause Windows any problems?  I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit, and memory and CPU power won't be an issue.

Comment: Are these child processes dependent on each other?

Comment: Regardless of if it will cause any *hard* problems, it will likely be slower due the extra context switching and bookkeeping the OS will need to do.

Comment: Can't you group the plugins in some way? Spawning hundreds of processes on Windows feels a bit risky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have enough CPU power and memory there are no problems. Having the general rules for distributed applications, multithreading (yes, multithreading), deadlocks, atomic operations and co. everything should be fine.